# How to wait on Json Data being put into my ObservableCollection, before executing other methods?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have 2 methods that extracts Json data inside my singleton. Currently my program just continues executing, before the methods are done, which results in my singleton lists containing 0 objects and therefore not printing anything to my gui. I changed the names to something generic, as my naming is in Danish.

My constructor where i run the methods:

```
    private SingletonConstructor()
    {
        ObsListe1 = new ObservableCollection<ListeObj1>();
        ObsListe2 = new ObservableCollection<ListeObj2>();
        LoadListe1Json();
        LoadListe2Json();
    }
```

And my Json methods, I use newtonsoft Json:

```
    private async Task LoadListe1Json()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile LocalFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName1);
            String jsonSaveData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(LocalFile);
            ObsListe1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ListeObj1>>(jsonSaveData);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadListe2Json()
    {
        try {
            StorageFile LocalFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName2);
            String jsonSaveData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(LocalFile);
            ObsListe2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ListeObj2>>(jsonSaveData);
        } catch
        {
        }
     }
```

I want the program to wait on the lists being set in my Json methods, before entering other methods in other classes. Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the task to complete, you can use [Task.Wait()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
LoadListe1Json().Wait();
```

Comment: The problem is, when I try to wait the task, It will stop at this:
String jsonSaveData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(LocalFile);
and just keep hanging there..

Comment: Yes I can open it, and It is created by myself. It's a .json format.